# Instance search in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have below array:

```
UT.insert({
            "chatUsers": [{
                        firstName: "John",
                        lastName: "Doe"
                    }, {
                        firstName: "Anna",
                        lastName: "Smith"
                    }, {
                        firstName: "Peter",
                        lastName: "Jones"
                    }
```

I have wrote below code with regular expression to traverse the array:

```
var selector = {
    chatUsers: [{
        firstName: regExp
    }, {
        lastName: regExp
    }]
};
console.log("UA" + UT.find(selector, options).fetch())
```

But its not returning anything. Advise me to do this.

This is my code:

```
if (searchText) {
    console.log("searchText")
    var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
    var selector = {
        chatUsers: [{
            firstName: regExp
        }, {
            lastName: regExp
        }]
    };
    console.log("UA" + UT.find(selector, options).fetch())

    return UT.find(selector, options).fetch();

} else {
    return UT.find({}, options).fetch();
}
});
```

This where I have wrote the expression:

```
function buildRegExp(searchText) {
    // this is a dumb implementation
    var parts = searchText.trim().split(/[ \-\:]+/);
    return new RegExp("(" + parts.join('|') + ")", "ig");
}
```

Comment: Try http://regexr.com to troubleshoot your RegExes before you fret with them in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

### This is working fine

```
var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
console.log("searchText :" + regExp)
var selector = {chatUsers: { $all: [
{ "$elemMatch" : { firstName: {$regex:regExp}, {$regex:regExp} }   },                                   
                              ]
              }}
console.log("serach Result ::"+UT.find(selector).fetch())
//This where I have wrote the expression:
function buildRegExp(searchText) {

return new RegExp("^"+searchText,"ig")
}
```